# Referencing a table using PyQt5 on a custom form in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, qcomobox

I am currently trying to add logic to a custom form to key out a habitat code. This is for work using [UK Habitat Classification](http://ecountability.co.uk/ukhabworkinggroup-ukhab/). 
It is based on a 5 level hierarchical code to produce a Primary Code. Each level filters the options for the next layer.

What I have so far (I stopped at level 3):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


Prime = None
L1Field = None
L2LField = None
L2CField = None
L3LField = None
L3CField = None

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    global Prime
    Prime = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"PRIME_COD")
    global L1Field
    L1Field = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"L1")
    L1Field.addItems(["","Terrestrial","Freshwater","Marine"])
    L1Field.currentIndexChanged.connect( L1Changed )
    global L2LField
    L2LField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"L2_LABEL")
    global L2CField
    L2CField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"L2_CODE")
    L2LField.currentIndexChanged.connect( L2Changed )
    global L3LField
    L3LField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"L3_LABEL")
    global L3CField
    L3CField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"L3_CODE")
    L3LField.currentIndexChanged.connect( L3Changed )


def L1Changed( value ):
    L2LField.clear()
    L3LField.clear()
    if L1Field.currentText() == 'Terrestrial':
        L2LField.addItems(["","Cropland","Grassland","Heathland and shrub","Sparsely vegetated land","Urban","Wetland","Woodland and forest"])
    elif L1Field.currentText() == 'Freshwater':
        L2LField.addItems(["Rivers and lakes"])
    elif L1Field.currentText() == 'Marine':
        L2LField.addItems(["Marine inlets and transitional waters"])
    else:
        L2LField.addItems([""])

def L2Changed( value ):
    L3LField.clear()
    if L2LField.currentText() == 'Grassland':
        L2CField.setText( 'g' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Acid grassland","Calcareous grassland","Neutral grassland","Modified grassland"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Woodland and forest':
        L2CField.setText( 'w' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Broadleaved mixed and yew woodland","Coniferous woodland"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Heathland and shrub':
        L2CField.setText( 'h' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Dwarf shrub heath","Hedgerows","Dense scrub"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Wetland':
        L2CField.setText( 'f' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Bog","Fen marsh and swamp"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Cropland':
        L2CField.setText( 'c' )
        L3LField.addItems(["Arable and horticulture"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Urban':
        L2CField.setText( 'u' )
        L3LField.addItems(["Built-up areas and gardens"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Sparsely vegetated land':
        L2CField.setText( 's' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Inland rock","Supralittoral Rock","Supralittoral Sediment"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Rivers and lakes':
        L2CField.setText( 'r' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Standing open water and canals","Rivers and streams"])
    elif L2LField.currentText() == 'Marine inlets and transitional waters':
        L2CField.setText( 't' )
        L3LField.addItems(["","Littoral Rock","Littoral Sediment"])
    else:
        L2CField.setText( '' )

def L3Changed (value):
    if L3LField.currentText() == 'Acid grassland':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Calcareous grassland':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Neutral grassland':
        L3CField.setText( '3' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Modified grassland':
        L3CField.setText( '4' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Broadleaved mixed and yew woodland':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Coniferous woodland':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Dwarf shrub heath':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Hedgerows':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Dense scrub':
        L3CField.setText( '3' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Bog':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Fen marsh and swamp':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Arable and horticulture':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Built-up areas and gardens':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Inland rock':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Supralittoral Rock':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Supralittoral Sediment':
        L3CField.setText( '3' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Standing open water and canals':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Rivers and streams':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Littoral Rock':
        L3CField.setText( '1' )
    elif L3LField.currentText() == 'Littoral Sediment':
        L3CField.setText( '2' )
    else:
        L3CField.setText( '' )
```

I have made a simple form in Qt Designer to test this. [image: Form]

My code works but I feel is cumbersome and could be greatly simplified but I lack the knowledge how. I would like to reference a table with the values to simplify things. I think it needs to be a table rather than lists as the Label field value sets the Code value and the previous level Label controls the drill down function on the Label QComboBox.

[image: Table]

Any help or recommendations to improve would be welcome.

N.B. I have not yet written the code to populate the Primary Field but this will be a concatenation of the L0CFields triggered on index change of any of these fields, I just haven't worked out how yet...

Comment: What data format is the table in?  Are you wanting to know how to connect and query against it?

Comment: It can be in any format that will work, CSV or DBF is easiest for me. I have looked at panda but not sure if it is right for this application. I need to know how to connect/reference a table so I can bring the values over to populate QComboBoxes and QTextEdit fields live based on values defined in other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a .csv using pyqgis you may use this method:

```
table = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Temp/Book1.csv', "table", "ogr")
```

To cursor through the records and columns use this method:

```
for record in table.getFeatures():
    print('L3_LABLE = {}, 'L3CODE = {}'.format(record['L3_LABLE'], record['L3_CODE']))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still not quite there with it yet but that's no doubt down to my total inexperience with scripting. I will plug away at it when I have time. Does the QgsVectorLayer address have to be absolute or can it be relative to the project file?